# 'Every two' as synonymous with 'every other'

Tags: grammar, synonyms, adverbs

In the sentence "a copy for every two people", i.e. 'to share", would **every two** be synomymous with **every other,** where the latter would be used in the same sense as it is used in "I used to visit her every other week"?

Comment: _Every other_ means 'in sequence'. If you give a copy to every other person, you give one to the first person you approach, none to the second, one to the third, none to the fourth, and so on. Sharing is up to them. If you provide a copy for every two people, you simply provide one-half as many copies as people. Again, without explicit information, sharing is up to the recipients.

Comment: In practice, *I go every other week* and *I go every two weeks* are equivalent. I suppose that's really just because the Arrow of Time dictates that there's *always* a natural sequence (and concept of "consecutive") for weeks, but there's no such equivalent for "people" (who might want a printed copy of something).

Comment: As it is, this question belongs on the [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange. However, if you rephrase it as a question about **when** the two constructions are equivalent, and when not, and if you show a bit of preliminary research, then you'd have a nice on-topic question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they are not synonymous.

In common usage:

- with "a copy for every two people", two people share one copy, as you indicate; whereas
- with "a copy for every other person", one person from each pair gets a copy and the other misses out.

There is no sharing implied in the "every other person" case.

Comment: Interestingly, however, they **are** interchangeable in such constructions as *we are getting paid [every other week] /[every two weeks].*

Comment: @linguisticturn Interesting, indeed - something's happening there that doesn't translate to the *copy* example. However, I think the "for" is important - getting paid "*for* every other week" isn't the same as getting paid "*for* every two weeks". Including the 'for' changes the sense of the *paid* example to parallel the *copy* example.